# The particle textures I make in photoshop look amazing, but very different in Unity Engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, photoshop, effects, particles

[image: Problem example image]

I handpaint textures in photoshop that look great and crisp, but in Unity Engine look like they have the alpha cranked down (they don't) and are very fuzzy and kind of transparent.  I've looked at project settings, import settings, messed with saving as TGA vs. PNG, changed DPI just to test even though I knew it wouldn't matter, kinda running out of ideas.

I've opened textures from materials I've got from the asset store for particles to check everything and I can't see what's different and what is causing my issue.  Please let me know if you have any idea what I can look at or try!

Comment: pictures or it didn't happen 

Comment: You need to give more information so the problem can be diagnosed.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1071303/how-to-fix-overly-blurred-texture-image-in-unity.html

Comment: @gman added image although clicked before changing description, sorry about that.

Comment: @aryamccarthy what information would be helpful?

Comment: @Maakep thank you for the link, lots of good stuff to try, unfortunately it didn't make a difference in my case.  let me know if you can think of anything else, thanks!

Comment: ok I realize that this image is not fuzzy, it's just one example, but it *is* dark.  HOWEVER if anyone's having the same problem I realized something very simple that I overlooked.  The alpha was not cranked down in the inspector, but it WAS, as well as the color dropped to a gray, above the place where you drag a texture when creating a new material.  Embarrassing but glad to have found it eventually:)  Honestly it still doesn't look like it's fully fixed but it's easily a dozen times better than it was

Comment: Just going to add I would expect it has to do with the material and/or shader you're using on the particles. Some shaders multiply by a color, other shaders multiply by lighting.  I'm sure there are some materials / shaders that apply none of that that will give you exactly what you made